# sam-cli local invoke error: Docker timeout after few seconds

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm working on macOS High Sierra, and trying to run sam-cli to debug my lambdas locally. Lambda runtime is nodejs8.10, SAM CLI, version 0.4.0

I use the following command

`sam local invoke --event payload.json --debug-port 5858 [lambdaName] --profile [profileName]`

The debugger gets invoked and i'm able to debug the lambda code for a while before the docker timeout occurs.

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sam", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('aws-sam-cli==0.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'sam')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 44, in cli
    docker_network, log_file, skip_pull_image, profile)  # pragma: no cover
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/invoke/cli.py", line 76, in do_cli
    stderr=context.stderr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/commands/local/lib/local_lambda.py", line 80, in invoke
    stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/local/lambdafn/runtime.py", line 98, in invoke
    container.wait_for_logs(stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/container.py", line 187, in wait_for_logs
    self._write_container_output(logs_itr, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/container.py", line 206, in _write_container_output
    for frame_type, data in output_itr:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/attach_api.py", line 98, in _read_socket
    payload_type, payload_size = _read_header(socket)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samcli/local/docker/attach_api.py", line 170, in _read_header
    data = read_exactly(socket, 8)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/socket.py", line 47, in read_exactly
    next_data = read(socket, n - len(data))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/socket.py", line 31, in read
    return socket.recv(n)
socket.timeout: timed out`
```

This is my sam template

```
`AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    lambda Description

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 300

Resources:
    LambdaName:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
            Handler: index.handler
            Runtime: nodejs8.10
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED : "0"
                    BUCKET_NAME : "bucketName"
                    KEY_NAME : "file.json"
                    DYNAMO_RULE_TABLE : "TableName"
                NODE_ENV: "development" # NODE_ENV: "production"`
```

I'm unable to find the root cause for this issue.

Comment: Can you clarify- do you mean that your lambda invokes for five minutes and then times-out?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace I meant the SAM local starts and VS code debugger is able to bind to the debugging port, I'm able to debug few lines and the debugger terminates suddenly throwing the above error.